# In Yii, where would be the proper place to put a function that fetches date() in a MySQL-appropriate storage format

Tags: php, yii

I am using `$model->created = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");` to get the current datetime in a MySQL friendly format pretty often and want to can that little bit into somewhere appropriate for reuse. I realize that there are many ways to do this, but what is the "Yii" way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a BaseModel, which most of the models inherit from. I perform the setting of dateCreated in the `beforeSave()` function if it isn't set. Also, I am using an component called LocalTime. See http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/197/local-time-zones-and-locales/

```
class BaseModel extends CActiveRecord {

    protected function beforeSave() {

        parent::beforeSave();

        if($this->hasAttribute('dateCreated') && $this->isNewRecord)
            $this->dateCreated = Yii::app()->localtime->getUTCNow();

        ...

        return $this;
    }
```

If you decide to use the LocalTime component, make sure you convert back to the local time from UTC on find:

```
protected function afterFind() {

    parent::afterFind();

    if($this->hasAttribute('dateCreated'))
        $this->dateCreated = Yii::app()->localtime->fromUTC($this->dateCreated);

    ...

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: it would be more transparent if u put it in the setter

Comment: @SamuelLiew, I think he just means that it might not be obvious what's going on to someone who is not familiar with your base model class cus it's buried in the `beforeSave()`, but personally that works for my purposes! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use yii's built-in behavior named [`CTimestampBehavior`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CTimestampBehavior).

```
   class YourModel extends CActiveRecord 
   {
        public function behaviors()
        {
            return array(
                'CTimestampBehavior' => array(
                    'class' => 'zii.behaviors.CTimestampBehavior',
                    'createAttribute'=>'created',
                )
            );
        }

    }
```

It is highly customizable. You can also specify [`updateAttribute`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CTimestampBehavior#updateAttribute-detail) to set the update time, [`timestampExpression`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CTimestampBehavior#timestampExpression-detail) to specify an alternate date format etc etc.